# Having trouble with moving a drawable in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imageview, android-drawable

I'm having trouble with some code I've set up that allows me to move an imageView's drawable to another imageView simply by clicking on the two imageViews (one with source image and then destination imageView) in succession.

The goal is to simulate a chessboard.

My starting display is the following: [image]

And after I click the leftmost pawn then click the square directly in front of it, the result is the following. You'll see that the target imageView (first column 3rd row) is losing its horizontal boundary definition and expanding across the entire tableRow:
[image]

Now, I'm also resetting tags along with the drawables in each square but I'd imagine that the issue stems from the way in which I'm getting and setting the drawables.

My code is as follows:

```
int selectedId = getResources().getIdentifier(selectedSquare, "id", getPackageName());

ImageView sourceSquare = (ImageView) findViewById(selectedId);

Drawable sourceDrawable = sourceSquare.getDrawable();

ImageView targetSquare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s20);
targetSquare.setImageDrawable(sourceDrawable);
```

My guess is that the `sourceDrawable` variable I'm creating somehow grabs too much or too little information and when I move that drawable into the new imageView `targetSquare` this destroys my formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the new ImageView the source LayoutParams of the origin:

```
targetSquare.setLayoutParams(sourceSquare.getLayoutParams);
```